# Do transformers have success in other domains different than NLP?

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language-processing, applications, sequence-modeling, transformer

Everybody knows how successful transformers have been in NLP. Is there known work on other domains (e.g that also have a sequential natural way of occurring, such as stock price prediction or other problems)?

Comment: Image generation with transformers instead of GANs is a thing.

Comment: do you have a paper or a reference?

Comment: https://cdn.openai.com/papers/Generative_Pretraining_from_Pixels_V2.pdf see also the completions section at their website.  https://openai.com/blog/image-gpt/

Comment: I've recently start seeing transformer-based models being used for traffic forecasting. Here is an example: https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.02908

Comment: @razvanc92 Although this is an old question, you can provide a formal answer below. Comments are meant to be temporary.

Comment: @thepacker As I told razvanc92, you can provide a formal answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it talks to other domains such as image or music, using transformer will always face a problem of sequence length limitation. To the best of my knowledge, the bottleneck of self-attention which uses a $n^2$ matrix quite limits transformer being applied to other domains. For example, a 32x32 pixel image, means a sequence of 1024 tokens.

OpenAI did some related research, as the followings.

[Generative Modeling with Sparse Transformers](https://openai.com/blog/sparse-transformer/):
In the paper, transformers with sparse attention are applied to image and waveform.

[ImageGPT](https://openai.com/blog/image-gpt/):
A large transformer model trained on language can generate coherent text, the same exact model trained on pixel sequences can generate coherent image completions and samples. (Abstract from the blog)

Comment: You may also want to mention the _vision transformer_.